# A Mongoose schema that embed another schema containing a unique key

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have two mongoDB schemas:

```
 /*--------------PRODUCTS SCHEMA------------------*/
var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  { name : {type:String, index:{ unique: true }}, price : Number });

/*--------------KOT SCHEMA-------------------------*/
var kotSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
   { products:{ type:[productSchema], required: "Products cannot be blank" });
```

When I am trying to save a new KOT with a product that already exists in a previously saved KOT document, I get the following mongoose error:
**MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection:**

I only want the name field of productSchema to be unique. However I should be able to save KOT's which may share the same products with other KOT documents in the database.
There is no *index:{unique:true}* property set for kotSchema. Then why am I getting the duplicate error? And how can I define the schemas to resolve this error?

Comment: I think, you can try giving ref. in KOT, product:{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Object, ref:"productSchema"}

Comment: I used Data Association by reference earlier but that was causing some issues for me so changed to Embedded Data. Everything was working fine till the time I introduced the unique index in my schemas to avoid duplicate entries. I didnot know that this will impact other schemas using embedded data..although I am still not sure if this is the real issue..